# Train Tensorfow model with larger than memory dataset (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, tensorflow, chunks

I have a dataset that's way larger than memory (a few hundreds gigabytes) in CSV format that I have to use as a training set for a Tensorflow model.
Using small example datasets is no problem, just load everything in memory and go; but what should the best strategy to handle this problem be?

I'm guessing the only way is to process the file in chunks; problem is that the cost should be calculated on the whole training set. I figured as a solution to do a few epochs on the largest chunk possible (and calculate the cost only on the data in the chunk), then do the next few epochs on the next chunk, and so on (maybe trying to make the model "see" each chunk more than once).

Is this the only solution, and is it reasonable? Or is there any other better approach?

Comment: You can first read their [doc](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception#how-to-fine-tune-a-pre-trained-model-on-a-new-task) on retraining Inception v3.

Comment: That's actually how things are done by default -- ie, minimizing cross entropy over the large dataset that doesn't fit in memory is done by minimizing cross-entropy on chunks (batches)